# How to get json using django and jquery ajax? got 500 Intenal server error

Tags: jquery, python, django

I'm trying to show dynamicly details of a certain object, getting them from a sqlite3 database. I based my code on a tutorial, everything is exactly the same, but I get a 500 Internal Server Error on my page (but the tutorial runs perfectly).

I have python 3.3 and django 1.6 installed.

Here's my code:

url.py :

```
url(r'^cargar-inmueble/(?P<id>\d+)$', 'inmobiliaria.views.cargar_inmueble', name='cargar_inmueble_view'),
```

views.py :

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from inmobiliaria.models import *

....

def cargar_inmueble(request, id):
    if request.is_ajax():
        inmueble = Inmueble.objects.get(id=id)
        return HttpResponse( json.dumps({'nombre': inmueble.nombre,
        'descripcion': inmueble.descripcion, 'foto' : inmueble.foto }),
        content_type='application/json; charset=utf8')
    else:
        raise Http404
```

hover.js (it's the main js script, have to rename it)

```
$(document).on("ready", inicio );

function inicio() {

    ...

    $("#slider ul li.inmueble").on("click", "a", cargar_inmueble);
}

function cargar_inmueble(data) {

    var id = $(data.currentTarget).data('id');

    $.get('cargar-inmueble/' + id, ver_inmueble);

}
```

Looking at the console of the chrome dev tools, everytime I click the link that calls "cargar_inmueble", I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZyup.png) and "ver_inmueble" is never called.. It's my first web site using python so I'm pretty lost!

Answer (score 0):

Check network tab of chrome dev tools then you will know the source of the problem.

Another way to debug is to simplify your view:

```
def cargar_inmueble(request, id):
    inmueble = Inmueble.objects.get(id=id)
    return HttpResponse( json.dumps({'nombre': inmueble.nombre,
        'descripcion': inmueble.descripcion, 'foto' : inmueble.foto }),
        content_type='application/json; charset=utf8')
```

Then go to `http://localhost:8000/cargar-inmueble/1` directly and you will see the stack trace if you leave `DEBUG=True` in `settings.py`.

Most likely this line can cause the error:

```
inmueble = Inmueble.objects.get(id=id)
```

When `id` doesn't exist, the it will throw DoesNotExist exception, you should catch it. Also I believe returning JSON is a bit different to what you are doing:

```
def cargar_inmueble(request, id):
    try:
        inmueble = Inmueble.objects.get(id=id)
    except Inmueble.DoesNotExist: # catch the exception
        inmueble = None

    if inmueble:
        json_resp = json.dumps({
            'nombre': inmueble.nombre,
            'descripcion': inmueble.descripcion, 
            'foto' : inmueble.foto 
        })
    else:
       json_resp = 'null'

    return HttpResponse(json_resp, mimetype='application/json')
```

Of course you can use [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) for simpler code. I just wanna show the basic idea.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I guess, instead of
json_resp = '', 

json_resp = 'null' would be better. The JSON parser on the client side would take '' as invalid JSON.

Comment: Yeah right, I guess I'm too sleepy to make an answer now. Thanks